# Global javascript event intercept/handling

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have a large website where a sub-portion of it is rendered by a framework (i.e. React, Vue, Angular...).
What I need is a way to handle/intercept all input events (e.g. focus, onchange, onclick ...) so that I can capture telemetry of all user inputs.

My initial brute-force approach was to add telemetry capturing at the framework level (so that all button clicks are captured). But then I realized all the input controls that are *rendered outside of the framework(s) will not be captured.*

Now I'm going back to the drawing board and wondering if this is even feasible.

I can't think of a way, even if its an ugly way, to cover all input events across the board.

Question:

How to intercept/handle all input events regardless of propagated events or not, and regardless of frameworks used?

Comment: What do you mean by *all input events*? AFAIK, there is no such type of events. `input` is just the name of one `UIEvent`. `focus` is a `FocusEvent`, `onchange` is `UIEvent`, `onclick` is a `MouseEvent`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example records the value whenever the value of the  element is changed.

It doesn't matter what framework you use or what events you handle at other points.

**Handle specific event:**

```js
var inputs = document.querySelector("input");

inputs.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  console.log('input value!', event.target.value, event.data);
});
```

```html
Input <input type="text">
```

**Handle all events:**

```js
var inputs = document.querySelector("input");
for (var ev in inputs) {
    // Events starts with "on" -> onClick, onInput, ...
    if (/^on/.test(ev)) {
        document.addEventListener(ev.substring(2), someFunction);
    }
}

function someFunction(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    console.log(event.type);
  }
};

function createInput() {
  var new_input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  new_input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
  document.body.appendChild(new_input);
}
```

```html
Input <input type="text">
<br>
<button onclick="createInput()">Create Input</button>
```

**EDITED:** Added example to capture all events.

**EDITED:** Capture dynamically created input events.

Comment: Thanks. this is brilliant.

Comment: But what about *all* other events?

Comment: @VLAZ New version can capture all events.

Comment: This will not register events on elements inserted into the DOM dynamically later. It might be better to attach the event listener to `document` (perhaps a capturing one to register events before any other event listeners get the chance to prevent bubbling by calling `stopPropagation`).

Comment: @John - Thank you for using good grammar, punctuation, and providing an elegant/simple/easy-to-follow snippets. This is an amazing answer.